# Java how to read a 64 bit unsigned long from a byte stream

Tags: java

I'm trying to read an unsigned long from byte stream (that has been generated by a C program). Since the number might be too big for a Java `long` I imagined the best way to do this would be to read the 8 bytes into a BigInteger (as below) but this doesn't work.

Would appreciate any help with a good way to do this.

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[8]).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    bb.putLong(12345678910L);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        bytes[i] = bb.get(i);
    }

    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bytes);// bi is not correct
```

Comment: That code would work if your `ByteOrder.nativeOrder()` was BIG_ENDIAN.  You can try it out by hard-coding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking out the order call:

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[8]);
    bb.putLong(12345678910L);
```

Comment: Better yet specify the byte order of the system the c program ran on. ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN or ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN